# Pagination in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

My request is as below . The EmpNumberList will have 250 EmpNumbers separated by space.

```
<soapenv:Body>      
     <v1:MRRequestParam>
        <v1:EmpNumberList><v1:EmpNumber>    9989071005 2004421004</v1:EmpNumber></v1:EmpNumberList>
     </v1:MRRequestParam>       
</soapenv:Body>
```

The XSLT I need to write should count the EmpNumbers from the EmpNumbersList
I need to call stored procedure in my XSLT such that i make 5 calls .
In one call I pass only 50 EmpNumbers. 
I make 5 calls in total

First Call will have $EmpNumber1 such that it contains 50 EmpNumbers

```
$EmpNumber1 =     9989071005    2004421004 (so on 50 EmpNumbers)

<argument type="SQL_VARCHAR" mode="INPUT" nullable="true" precision="0" scale="0" isNull="false"><xsl:value-of select="$EmpNumber1" />
</argument>
```

When I send back the response I need to club all 5 result set and send at a time.
Please let me know if you have any suggestions

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a one-liner XPath solution. :)

Comment: If this is a clarification of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797033/xslt-count-request-elements), do note that we expect that you **update** your questions instead of asking the same again. What if these answers doesn't solve your problem? Are you going to ask it for the third time?

Answer (score 2):

This one is easy:

**Use**:

```
string-length(translate(normalize-space(/*/*/*/v1:EmpNumber), '0123456789',''))+1
```

When applied on this document (the provided one with one more number):

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="my:soapenv">
    <v1:MRRequestParam xmlns:v1="my:v1">
        <v1:EmpNumberList>
            <v1:EmpNumber>    9989071005 2004421004 1234567890 </v1:EmpNumber>
        </v1:EmpNumberList>
    </v1:MRRequestParam>
</soapenv:Body>
```

**the wanted, correct result is returned:**

```
3
```

**Here is a complete XSLT 1.0 stylesheet to run and verify that the correct results are always produced**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:soapenv="my:soapenv" xmlns:v1="my:v1">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select=
      "string-length(
            translate(normalize-space(/*/*/*/v1:EmpNumber), '0123456789','')
                     )+1"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**: You have to specify the correct namespaces in the transformation and in the XML document -- you haven't provided them in your question.

**Explanation**:

The meaning of this expression:

```
      string-length(
            translate(normalize-space(/*/*/*/v1:EmpNumber), '0123456789','')
                     )+1
```

is:

1. [**`normalize-space()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space) . This takes the string and produces a new string from it, in which all leading and trailing whitespace characters are deleted.
2. **What remains are only the numbers with just one intermediate space character between every two numbers**. So, if there are N numbers, the number of spaces is N-1.
3. **The [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate) function as referenced in the expression, returns a new string in which all digits are gone** (replaced by the empty string ''. What remains are only the space characters.
4. **Using the [`string-length()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string-length) function** we simply get the count of those spaces** (N-1). We add 1 and get the number N of all the numbers in the string.

Comment: I need to invoke stored proc which will accept 50 EmpNumbers per call. 
But front end is sending 250 records hence I need to make 5 calls to the backend. 

Note - If the count is > 250 we will send fault.
If count is 120 we will make 3 calls.

Also my EmpNumber is a 19 digit number so it is 4 spaces and 15 digits

Comment: @alisha: You need to *learn* how to ask a question well -- please look at other questions -- almost all of them are better formulated. The reason why you don't get the expected answer is the hopeless, undefined state of your questions. Edit. Improve.

Comment: @alisha: Are all the numbers in `v1:EmpNumber` with fixed number of digits? If so, what is this fixed number? Are the whitespaces preceding each number also of fixed length? If so, what is this fixed length?

Comment: Yes the number is having fixed lenght which is 19. It is 15 digits preceding with 4 spaces

Comment: @alisha: What does the stored procedure return? Please, explain and provide an example.

Comment: stored proc returns cursor result set -

Comment: <sql result="success"><parameter position="7">0</parameter><parameter position="8">SUCES</parameter><resultSet><metadata><columnInfo index="1" nullable="false" name="Id" precision="19" scale="0" type="SQL_CHAR" /><columnInfo index="2" nullable="false" name="Name" precision="10" scale="0" type="SQL_CHAR" /><columnInfo index="3" nullable="false" name="Age" precision="1" scale="0" type="SQL_CHAR" /></metadata><row><column><name>Id</name><value>2580658</value></column><column><name>Name</name><value>Alisha</value></column><column><name>Age</name><value>24</value></column></row></resultSet></sql>

Comment: @alisha: C'mon... If the stored procedure is called from XSLT it *must* return one of the allowed types in the XML Infoset (XPath 1.0), or XDM (XPath 2.0). Just invoke the SP from XSLT and provide the result (output `xsl:copy-of` whatever the SP returns). If you don't know what the SP returns, you *cannot* ask this question -- you simply don't know what the data is -- how can you ask someone to give you a solution how to put the data together?

Comment: @alisha: You must edit completely your question and put there understandably all the information that I forced you to provide piece by piece. Never again ask a question without understanding what it involves.